# How to obtain required content from "find_element_by_xpath"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium & python to auto get part of the html content.
I use find xpath like below ways to sort out the price from specified flight number, but always get failed result " unable to locate "
Anyone could shed some lights on it ?

```
element_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='flight_MU5401']")
element_price.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='base_price02']")
```

[It's the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZFil.png)

Comment: Please post your html code here

Comment: Use firefox bug tracker to get correct xpath

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. Also post the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess, I would say that you are probably getting that error because the element isn't loaded when your code runs. It's probably a slower loading page. You should try adding a wait and see if that helps.

You can also simplify your locator by using a CSS selector and only scraping the page once.

```
price = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#flight_MU5401 span.base_price02")).text
```

Comment: Thank you JeffC for your reply. I've tried yours.And it say:
AttributeError: visibility of element located object has no attribute 'text'